# Is there a good expression for the maximum character value in an SQL collation?

Tags: sql-server, collation

I'm building a simple SQL report that assembles possible product titles from several tables and displays unnamed products last. We have a setup that allows individual locations to override the product title from a master product table, and I thought I could do something like

```
SELECT a.ProdCode, COALESCE(a.ProdNameOverride, m.ProdName, '') AS ProdName
FROM ProdInventory a 
INNER JOIN MasterProdTable m ON a.ProdCode = m.ProdCode
WHERE a.ProdLocation = @ReportProdLocation
ORDER BY COALESCE(a.ProdNameOverride, m.ProdName, char(255)) ASC, a.ProdCode ASC
```

because, hey, `char(255)` has to sort after all of the other possible ASCII characters, right?

Well, no. It's a diacritical Y, which in the standard (SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) collation gets sorted before Z.

I eventually just resorted to brute force, finding that `char(254)` sorted after the conventional alphanumerics, but that got me curious - is there a reliable way to assign something "the last possible value in the relevant collation"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the last character in a varchar collation, you can just create a table with all possible characters and sort it.  eg:

```
declare @chars table
(
  CodePoint binary(1) primary key, 
  Character char(1) collate Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS
)

declare @codePoint binary(1) = 0x0
while (@codePoint < 255)
begin
  
 insert into @chars(CodePoint,Character) 
 values (@codePoint, cast(@codePoint as char(1)));

 set @codePoint += 1;
end

Select * 
from @chars
order by Character
```

Comment: Yes, this is how I found that char(254) showed up last. I suppose it's not too much overhead, but I called it "brute force" because I was expecting to be able to... query the collation, somehow?

Comment: You shouldn’t need to do that at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

### Even if it were reliable, sort by what you actually want last.

This report is assuming nobody could ever enter a product override that began with the last possible character. You can't be sure of that, even if `char(254)` doesn't show up on conventional keyboards.

If you want products to appear last when they have a `NULL` override and main product name, construct a sort using `CASE WHEN` around that condition, as:

```
SELECT a.ProdCode, COALESCE(a.ProdNameOverride, m.ProdName, '') AS ProdName
FROM ProdInventory a 
INNER JOIN MasterProdTable m ON a.ProdCode = m.ProdCode
WHERE a.ProdLocation = @ReportProdLocation
ORDER BY CASE WHEN a.ProdNameOverride IS NULL AND m.ProdName IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC,
   COALESCE(a.ProdNameOverride, m.ProdName) ASC, a.ProdCode ASC
```